# Sort(Rearrange) your customer my account navigation link

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, customer-account, navigation

I was struggling to sorting the customer account navigation link out of the box.But was unable to find out proper solution to rearrange this navigation.

So i google and get some idea to make it possible.

I got some idea from the suggestion of @marius from this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18615647/change-the-order-of-navigation-in-my-account-page-in-magento)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution about above question.

Overwrite the `Navigation.php` File in your local folder and write the below code in it.

```
class Namespace_Modulename_Block_Customer_Account_Navigation extends 

Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Navigation
{

public function getLinksByName($name)
{
return $this->_links[$name];
}

}
```

Now overwrite or make theme file change at  `template/customer/account/navigation.phtml`

```
    <div class="block block-account">

<div class="block-title">
<strong><span><?php echo $this->__('My Account'); ?></span></strong>
</div>


<div class="block-content">
<?php $_linkOrder = array('account', 'savecart', 'carpenterorder', 'warranty', 'supportticket','reports','account_edit','address_book','minicarpenter'); ?>

<ul>
<?php $_links = $this->getLinks(); ?>
<?php $_index = 1; ?>
<?php $_count = count($_links); ?>
<?php foreach ($_linkOrder as $linkName): ?>
<?php $OrderLinkobject = $this->getLinksByName($linkName); ?>
<?php if ($this->isActive($OrderLinkobject)): ?>

<li class="current<?php echo ($_last ? ' last' : '') ?>"><strong><?php echo $OrderLinkobject->getLabel() ?></strong></li>

<?php else: ?>
<li<?php echo ($_last ? ' class="last"' : '') ?>><a href="<?php echo $OrderLinkobject->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $OrderLinkobject->getLabel() ?></a></li>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php unset($_links[$linkName]) ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php foreach ($_links as $_link): ?>
<?php $_last = ($_index++ >= $_count); ?>
<?php if ($this->isActive($_link)): ?>

<li class="current<?php echo ($_last ? ' last' : '') ?>"><strong><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></strong></li>

<?php else: ?>
<li<?php echo ($_last ? ' class="last"' : '') ?>><a href="<?php echo $_link->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></a></li>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>

</div>

</div>
```

Here `$_linkOrder = array('account', 'savecart', 'carpenterorder', 'warranty', 'supportticket','reports','account_edit','address_book','minicarpenter');`

is my sorting order for specific link order rest will render by magento core.You can define name of your link in that array to sort.